# How to download Zip file from odoo Print menu?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

I'm using Odoo 9. I've to download Zip file from Print menu above a tree view.
Can this be achieved? and kindly tell me how to do this,  I tried some of the things but code is not returning zip file.

Comment: You have to override https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/report/controllers/main.py in order to compress the file attached

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I've done it through Action drop down adjacent to Print menu.

Comment: Therefore, write an aswer.